# Return string until matched string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How do you return the portion of a string until the first instance of `" #"` or `" Apt"`?

I know I could split the string up into an array based on `"#"` or `"Apt"` and then calling `.first`, but there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

String splitting is definitely easier and more readable than trying to extract the portion of the string using a regex. For the latter case, you would need a capture group to get the first match. It will be the same as string splitting

```
string.split(/#|Apt/, 2).first
```

Comment: It would be worth at least passing `2` as the second argument to `split` (meaning: split into at most two pieces) since you only want the first result. Otherwise this could potentially do a lot more work than necessary.

Comment: Fun fact:

name, token, rest = "Jane Doe #331-456".split(/\s*(#|Apt)/, 2)
# name = "Jane Doe", token = "#", rest = "331-456"

Answer (score 3):

I'd write a method to make it clear. Something like this, for example:

```
class String
    def substring_until(substring)
        i = index(substring)
        return self if i.nil?
        i == 0 ? "" : self[0..(i - 1)]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [String#[]](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/String#%5B%5D-instance_method) method. Like this:

```
[
  '#foo',
  'foo#bar',
  'fooAptbar',
  'asdfApt'
].map { |str| str[/^(.*)(#|Apt)/, 1] } #=> ["", "foo", "foo", "asdf"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't write in ruby all that much, but I'm sure you could use a regular expression along the lines of

```
^.*(#|Apt)
```

Or, if you put the string into a tokenizer, you could do something with that, but it'd be tougher considering you are looking for a word and not just a single character.